# Powershell matching by two values

Tags: powershell

I try to get all Processes with starting letter w or s

Something like this:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -Match "^w.*" -or ProcessName -Match "^s.*" | Select-Object name, ID
```

but this doesnt work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's either one or the other, in the same position, you can use character class group (`[characters]`):

```
Get-Process | Where-Object ProcessName -match '^[ws]' | ...
```

The `.*` at the end of either pattern is moot.

Answer (score 2):

For complex expressions that use the same operator more than once or require logical operators, you need to pass a script block to `Where-Object`:

```
Get-Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessName -Match "^w.*" -or $_.ProcessName -Match "^s.*" } | Select-Object name, ID
```

Though in this case, you don't really need a complex expression, [as Mathias R. Jessen has pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65936290/7571258).

Answer (score 1):

`Get-Process` supports [wildcards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_wildcards?view=powershell-7.1) in the `ProcessName` parameter, so in this case you don't need `Where-Object`:

`Get-Process -ProcessName '[ws]*' | Select-Object Name, ID`

Comment: Best answer so far.